# I'm trying to join 4 tables and 3 have their own index table shared with the first

Tags: mysql, join, union

This is the overall structure here: Altogether, there are 7 tables.
Game table (primary table)
perspective table
genre table
os table

Persepective, genre, and os has their own separate index table that connects them to the game table.

I figured using `JOIN` and `UNION` would allow me to construct results that has a column from each table. The Game table has about four columns, the other three not index tables has only one column that I need from them.

This is the command I'm using, but it only ever attaches the genre column from the genre table. It won't attach the other columns from the other two.

> MySQL>
>   (SELECT game.game_name, game.release_date, game.current_development, game.designer, genre.genre                 FROM gamegen    JOIN game ON gamegen.game_id = game.game_id    JOIN genre                   ON gamegen.genre_id = genre.genre_id                         WHERE game.game_id = 32)
>   UNION ALL
>   (SELECT game.game_name, game.release_date, game.current_development, game.designer, perspective.perspective_type           FROM gameper    JOIN game ON gameper.game_id = game.game_id    JOIN perspective             ON gameper.perspective_id = perspective.perspective_id       WHERE game.game_id = 32)
>   UNION ALL
>   (SELECT game.game_name, game.release_date, game.current_development, game.designer, operational_environment.system_name    FROM gameoe     JOIN game ON gameoe.game_id = game.game_id     JOIN operational_environment ON gameoe.oe_id = operational_environment.oe_id              WHERE game.game_id = 32)
>   ;

When I do it like this, all I ever get is the game table columns and the genre column from the genre table, but the perspective_type column from the perspective table won't show up, and the `system_type` column from the `operational_environment` table won't show up.

What am I missing?

Comment: it's better to work on http://sqlfiddle.com/ for such as questions.

Comment: Thanks ArK, for putting the code in that special window. I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Now I figured out how to edit it, I have to click "improve edit," but now I can't get the code to show back up in that nice way as before.

Comment: Thanks tanaydin, but it doesn't work. Keeps telling me I don't have permission to use the database I was trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these columns to the SELECT clause to get listed in the query output.

Comment: What do you mean? I have a separate SELECT JOIN statement for each table.

Do you mean to put them all in each select statement, because I tried that too, but it gives me an error because the join parts only mention the specific table I'm adding with that select statement.

Answer (score 0):

All your `SELECT` are based on the same condition (`WHERE game.game_id = 32`) and retrieving the same columns from the `game` table, only adding corresponding data by joining the 3 other tables (`genre`, `perspective` and `operational_environment`).

So may be you just need to use something like this?

```
SELECT game.*, genre.*, perspective.*, operational_environment.*
FROM game
JOIN gamegen ON gamegen.game_id = game.game_id
JOIN genre ON gamegen.genre_id = genre.genre_id
JOIN gameper ON gameper.game_id = game.game_id
JOIN perspective ON gameper.perspective_id = perspective.perspective_id
JOIN gameoe ON gameoe.game_id = game.game_id
JOIN operational_environment ON gameoe.oe_id = operational_environment.oe_id
WHERE game.game_id = 32;
```

Comment: Maybe, but I will have to test this and make sure it's consistently right because I don't understand what it's doing. How does it know across each table to reference the exact same line. Thanks for this. I will test it.

Comment: Initially, it looks like it's working, but it's repeating the operational environment.system_name column twice. It goes through each system name and then does it again.

Comment: I gave you the general idea using generic columns selection (`foo.*`). You can get just the columns you want by specifying them explicitly just after the `SELECT` word. If you get multiple lines, you may need to refine your selection by adding more conditions in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Alright, thanks. What's happening is anytime there's another entry for any of the other columns, the operating system column repeats the whole operating system list.

If there's 2 genres, it will repeat the operating system list twice. Same if there's two perspectives. If there's 3, it will repeat the operating system list 3 times.

Comment: Do you know of a way that I can change my SELECT JOIN UNION statements so that it adds the other columns as well. Maybe it will give me the same problem, but I wanted to see if it would.